Joined hatching
I'm trying to create hatching that resembles colouring in like this:

I understand the complexities around this so I'm trying to make it more uniform. My MWE currently can create hatching but the lines aren't joined.
MWE (w/ comments):
My code is wrong, but it's the closest I could do to resemble what I had in mind.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define the new command \hatch
% +-Note:------------------------------------
% | This is the closest as to what I could create as a function 
% | thereby this should taken with a grain of salt as this is
% | not what is the desired output 
% +------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\hatch}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Extract the width parameter
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{#2}
        % Extract the angle parameter
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{#3}
        
        % Draw the shape outline and clip
        \draw[opacity=0] plot coordinates {#1};
        \begin{scope}
            \clip plot coordinates {#1};
            
            % Determine bounding box of the shape
            \path (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
            
            % Calculate bounds for hatching lines
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \path plot coordinates {#1};
            \path (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
            
            % Draw hatching lines
            \foreach \x in {-20,-19.5,...,20} {
                \draw[line width=\width, rotate around={\angle:(0,0)}] (\x,-20) -- (\x+40,20);
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

% Example usage
\hatch{(0,0) (0,1) (10,1) (10,0) (0,0)}{5}{0.5}

\end{document}

Current Output:

Desired Output:

Question:
How would I have to modify my MWE to have the desired output?

Are you trying to fill the rectangle with this? Or are you trying to make a reusable pattern?

@cfr Trying to make a fillable polygon

Just if you clip it, how is it meant to end up joined?

@cfr I think MWE might be wrong - but it's there to show the community that I tried before asking. I've updated the question

@cfr it isn't supposed to be clipping, but more so to have a "boundary" as to where the hatching is supposed to happen.
